# Use detailCalloutAccessoryView as third Annotation property

Tags: swift, annotations, mapkit, calloutview

I am a newbie at Swift as well as Stackoverflow, and I was wondering if there is a way to import data from my plist to detailCalloutAccesoryView in the same manner as I import to "title" and "subtitle" in my map annotation callouts? This way, I could avoid having to make my own custom map annotation, and rather use the built-in features of MapKit.

I am calling my variables to title and subtitle like this:

```
var myData: NSArray?
        if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("myData", ofType: "plist") {
            myData = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path)
        }
        if let items = myData {
            for item in items {
                let lat = item.valueForKey("Latitude") as! Double
                let long = item.valueForKey("Longitude") as! Double
                let myAnnotation = Mydata(value1: "Value1", value2: "Value2", value3: "Value3", latitude: lat, longitude: long)
                // Define "Value1 to be shown as title in Callout
                myAnnotation = item.valueForKey("Value1") as? String
                // Define "Value2 to be shown as subtitle in Callout
                myAnnotation.subtitle = item.valueForKey("Value2") as? String
                annotations.append(myAnnotation)
            }
        }
        return annotations
    }
```

By now, I am just showing the same value in all annotations for detailCalloutAccessoryView in the place of subtitle using the following piece code:

```
let detailAccessory = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,50,30))
        detailAccessory.text = "Value3" // Obviously, shows constant value for all annotations
        detailAccessory.font = UIFont(name: "Verdana", size: 10)
        pinView?.detailCalloutAccessoryView = detailAccessory
```

Please, do not let my ignorance annoy you...

Answer (score 1):

You will need to implement func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? delegate method. In there you can customize detailCalloutAccessoryView.

For detailed explanation refer to https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/206/